# stata logistic regression error code due to missing values- what can I do?

Tags: syntax-error, regression, stata, logistic-regression, missing-data

I am performing a logistic regression

`regress igg1ugml age_years term_spec cesareansection estradiollevels breastfeed_howlong, robust`

when I run the code with both estradiollevels and breastfeed_howlong, it leads to the error. When I run it without one of those variables, it leads to an output.

Neither variables are string variables. However, they do hold many missing values (256/334) for breastfeed_howlong and (270/334) for estradiollevels

What can I do about this? I would like to include both variables in my analysis.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Can we see the code?

Comment: code updated above

when I run the code with both estradiollevels and breastfeed_howlong, it leads to the error. When I run it without one of those variables, it leads to an output.

Neither variables are string variables. However, they do hold many missing values (256/334) for breastfeed_howlong and (270/334) for estradiollevels

What can I do about this? I would like to include both variables in my analysis.

Comment: You must either drop those variables or impute missing values. Logistic regression doesn’t work with missing data.

Comment: what do you mean impute missing values? my missing have been given "."

Comment: On the face of it this isn't a programming question: it is a statistical question about what to do with many missing values. @AryaMcCarthy's summary seems spot on to me.

Comment: Note that `regress` does not perform logistic regression.